# Version history button Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, version-history

Is there any way how to insert `"Version History"` button from **Ribbon** to page or **displayform.aspx** in `SP List`?

Thanks a lot.
Dominik

Answer (score 1):

You can add this code:

```
`<a href="#" onclick="SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog( {url: '/_layouts/Versions.aspx?list={list guid}&ID={item id}&IsDlg=1'} ); return false;">version history</a>`
```